# jQuery address plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-address

I would like to learn the basics of this plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Can someone show me a very simple example of how it works (the very basic concept of it).

Thanks.

Comment: Which plug-in? This one? http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: sharing a link would help to help you

Comment: What? Asual jQuery Address? Dude, if you got the plugin, you know its home page, and every such page have samples and tutorials. Is that hard to check them out?

Comment: Have you got a more specific question about how it works? It’s a bit difficult to answer general “what is this about” questions.

Answer (score 3):

The plug-in’s website has [several examples](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/). View source on each one to see the use of the plug-in.

Comment: im pretty sure 2 of the examples use php. so looking at the source may seem a bit pointless if you want to know the full code..

Comment: @Ricki: ah — in what way do they use PHP? Given that jQuery is JavaScript, and thus runs entirely on the client-side, I assumed the examples wouldn’t rely on anything server-side, at least as far as “the basics” goes.

Comment: if you look at the docs, he says he uses php plus jQuery..

Comment: @Ricki: could you point to where? A search for "PHP" on the page http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/ returns nothing.

Comment: my mistake its on the samples page http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/

Comment: @Ricki: ah yes. So if I underatand correctly, you'd often use the plugin in conjunction with something (e.g. PHP) on the server-side, but the plug-in itself doesn't rely on (or include) any specific PHP code.

Comment: yes sorry, the plugin has no reliability on PHP at all, But some of the samples listed do use it. :D